# escape space comma doublequotes from yaml file

Tags: yaml

I want to write YAML file into influxdb. Inorder to do that I need to escape all special-characters as mentioned below.
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/write_protocols/line_protocol_reference/#special-characters

I have tried using sed command to escape space , comma and double quotes.

```
example: sed 's/ /\\ /g' | sed 's/\"//g' | sed 's/\,//g'
```

After escaping using sed command it didn't work for me while writing into influxdb.

I want to write below yaml file to influxdb for that I need to escape all special characters. I am not sure how to do this on yaml.

are there any command which will automatically escape all the special characters in the yaml file??
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/starkandwayne/concourse-tutorial/master/ci/pipeline.yml

Yaml format mentioned here worked fine for me. 
https://yaml.org/start.html

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the routine that dumps the dicts back to YAML, and explicitly set
the style for the values only, while also replacing any character that needs escaping (double
quotes are already escaped by the library):

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

pipeline = Path('pipeline.yaml')


def my_represent_dict(self, data):
    try:
        t = data.tag.value
    except AttributeError:
        t = None
    if t:
        if t.startswith('!!'):
            tag = 'tag:yaml.org,2002:' + t[2:]
        else:
            tag = t
    else:
        tag = u'tag:yaml.org,2002:map'
    result = self.represent_mapping(tag, data)
    # the original would now just return result
    for (key_node, value_node) in result.value:
        if value_node.tag != 'tag:yaml.org,2002:str':  # not a string
            continue
        value_node.style = '"'    # hard code the style
        for ch in ',= ':          # escape  
            value_node.value = value_node.value.replace(ch, '\\' + ch)
    return result

ruamel.yaml.representer.RoundTripRepresenter.add_representer(ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap, my_represent_dict)


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(pipeline)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
meta:
  name: "((\\ param\\ \"Please\\ name\\ your\\ pipeline\"\\ ))"
  team: "((\\ param\\ \"Please\\ provide\\ expected\\ concourse\\ team\\ to\\ deploy\\\
    \ test\\ pipelines\"\\ ))"
  pipeline: "((\\ grab\\ meta.name\\ ))"
  target: "((\\ param\\ \"Please\\ identify\\ the\\ name\\ of\\ the\\ target\\ Concourse\\\
    \ CI\"\\ ))"
  url: "((\\ param\\ \"Please\\ specify\\ the\\ full\\ url\\ of\\ the\\ target\\ Concourse\\\
    \ CI\"\\ ))"

  image:
    name: "starkandwayne/concourse"
    tag: "latest"

  github:
    uri: "((\\ concat\\ \"git@github.com:\"\\ meta.github.owner\\ \"/\"\\ meta.github.repo\\\
      \ ))"
    owner: "((\\ param\\ \"Please\\ specify\\ the\\ name\\ of\\ the\\ user\\ /\\ organization\\\
      \ that\\ owns\\ the\\ Github\\ repository\"\\ ))"
    repo: "((\\ param\\ \"Please\\ specify\\ the\\ name\\ of\\ the\\ Github\\ repository\"\
      \\ ))"
    branch_master: "master"
    branch_develop: "develop"
    private_key: "((\\ param\\ \"Please\\ generate\\ an\\ SSH\\ Deployment\\ Key\\\
      \ for\\ this\\ repo\\ and\\ specify\\ it\\ here\"\\ ))"
    access_token: "((\\ param\\ \"Please\\ generate\\ a\\ Personal\\ Access\\ Token\\\
      \ to\\ be\\ used\\ for\\ creating\\ github\\ releases\\ (do\\ you\\ have\\ a\\\
      \ ci-bot?)\"\\ ))"

  cf:
    api: "https://api.run.pivotal.io"
    skip_cert_check: false
    username: "((\\ param\\ \"please\\ provide\\ cf.username\"\\ ))"
    password: "((\\ param\\ \"please\\ provide\\ cf.password\"\\ ))"
    organization: "((\\ param\\ \"please\\ provide\\ cf.organization\"\\ ))"
    space: "((\\ param\\ \"please\\ provide\\ cf.space-production\"\\ ))"

    master:
      appname: "((\\ grab\\ meta.name\\ ))"
    develop:
      appname: "((\\ concat\\ meta.name\\ \"-develop\"\\ ))"

  concourse:
    url: "((\\ param\\ \"please\\ provide\\ concourse.url\"\\ ))"
    username: "((\\ param\\ \"please\\ provide\\ concourse.username\"\\ ))"
    password: "((\\ param\\ \"please\\ provide\\ concourse.password\"\\ ))"
    ca_cert: "((\\ param\\ \"please\\ provide\\ concourse.ca_cert\"\\ ))"

  credhub:
    url: "((\\ param\\ \"please\\ provide\\ credhub.url\"\\ ))"
    username: "((\\ param\\ \"please\\ provide\\ credhub.username\"\\ ))"
    password: "((\\ param\\ \"please\\ provide\\ credhub.password\"\\ ))"
    ca_cert: "((\\ param\\ \"please\\ provide\\ credhub.ca_cert\"\\ ))"

groups:
- name: "((\\ grab\\ meta.pipeline\\ ))"
  jobs:
  - testflight-develop
  - testflight-master
  - website-master
  - website-develop

jobs:
- name: "testflight-develop"
  public: false
  serial_groups: [tutorial-pipeline]
  plan:
  - get: "git"
    resource: "git-develop"
    trigger: true
  - task: "testflight"
    config:
      platform: "linux"
      image_resource:
        type: "docker-image"
        source:
          repository: "((\\ grab\\ meta.image.name\\ ))"
          tag: "((\\ grab\\ meta.image.tag\\ ))"
      inputs:
      - {name: "git"}
      run:
        path: "./git/ci/scripts/testflight-with-credhub.sh"
        args: []
      params:
        REPO_ROOT: "git"
        FLY_URL: "((\\ grab\\ meta.concourse.url\\ ))"
        FLY_TEAM: "((\\ grab\\ meta.team\\ ))"
        FLY_USERNAME: "((\\ grab\\ meta.concourse.username\\ ))"
        FLY_PASSWORD: "((\\ grab\\ meta.concourse.password\\ ))"
        FLY_CACERT: "((\\ grab\\ meta.concourse.ca_cert\\ ))"
        CREDHUB_URL: "((\\ grab\\ meta.credhub.url\\ ))"
        CREDHUB_USERNAME: "((\\ grab\\ meta.credhub.username\\ ))"
        CREDHUB_PASSWORD: "((\\ grab\\ meta.credhub.password\\ ))"
        CREDHUB_CACERT: "((\\ grab\\ meta.credhub.ca_cert\\ ))"
- name: "testflight-master"
  public: false
  serial_groups: [tutorial-pipeline]
  plan:
  - get: "git"
    resource: "git-master"
    trigger: true
  - task: "testflight"
    config:
      platform: "linux"
      image_resource:
        type: "docker-image"
        source:
          repository: "((\\ grab\\ meta.image.name\\ ))"
          tag: "((\\ grab\\ meta.image.tag\\ ))"
      inputs:
      - {name: "git"}
      run:
        path: "./git/ci/scripts/testflight-with-credhub.sh"
        args: []
      params:
        REPO_ROOT: "git"
        FLY_URL: "((\\ grab\\ meta.concourse.url\\ ))"
        FLY_TEAM: "((\\ grab\\ meta.team\\ ))"
        FLY_USERNAME: "((\\ grab\\ meta.concourse.username\\ ))"
        FLY_PASSWORD: "((\\ grab\\ meta.concourse.password\\ ))"
        FLY_CACERT: "((\\ grab\\ meta.concourse.ca_cert\\ ))"
        CREDHUB_URL: "((\\ grab\\ meta.credhub.url\\ ))"
        CREDHUB_USERNAME: "((\\ grab\\ meta.credhub.username\\ ))"
        CREDHUB_PASSWORD: "((\\ grab\\ meta.credhub.password\\ ))"
        CREDHUB_CACERT: "((\\ grab\\ meta.credhub.ca_cert\\ ))"

- name: "website-master"
  public: false
  serial: true
  plan:
  - get: "git"
    resource: "git-master"
    trigger: true
  - task: "mkdocs-build"
    config:
      platform: "linux"
      image_resource:
        type: "docker-image"
        source:
          repository: "((\\ grab\\ meta.image.name\\ ))"
          tag: "((\\ grab\\ meta.image.tag\\ ))"
      inputs:
      - {name: "git"}
      outputs:
      - {name: "site"}
      run:
        path: "./git/ci/scripts/mkdocs-build.sh"
        args: []
      params:
        REPO_ROOT: "git"
        SITE_ROOT: "site"
  - put: "deploy-master"
    params:
      manifest: "site/manifest-production.yml"
      path: "site"
      current_app_name: "((\\ grab\\ meta.cf.master.appname\\ ))"

- name: "website-develop"
  public: false
  serial: true
  plan:
  - get: "git"
    resource: "git-develop"
    trigger: true
  - task: "mkdocs-build"
    config:
      platform: "linux"
      image_resource:
        type: "docker-image"
        source:
          repository: "((\\ grab\\ meta.image.name\\ ))"
          tag: "((\\ grab\\ meta.image.tag\\ ))"
      inputs:
      - {name: "git"}
      outputs:
      - {name: "site"}
      run:
        path: "./git/ci/scripts/mkdocs-build.sh"
        args: []
      params:
        REPO_ROOT: "git"
        SITE_ROOT: "site"
  - put: "deploy-develop"
    params:
      manifest: "site/manifest-develop.yml"
      path: "site"
      current_app_name: "((\\ grab\\ meta.cf.develop.appname\\ ))"


resources:
- name: "git-develop"
  type: "git"
  source:
    uri: "((\\ grab\\ meta.github.uri\\ ))"
    branch: "((\\ grab\\ meta.github.branch_develop\\ ))"
    private_key: "((\\ grab\\ meta.github.private_key\\ ))"

- name: "git-master"
  type: "git"
  source:
    uri: "((\\ grab\\ meta.github.uri\\ ))"
    branch: "((\\ grab\\ meta.github.branch_master\\ ))"
    private_key: "((\\ grab\\ meta.github.private_key\\ ))"

- name: "deploy-develop"
  type: "cf"
  source:
    api: "((\\ grab\\ meta.cf.api\\ ))"
    skip_cert_check: "((\\ grab\\ meta.cf.skip_cert_check\\ ))"
    username: "((\\ grab\\ meta.cf.username\\ ))"
    password: "((\\ grab\\ meta.cf.password\\ ))"
    organization: "((\\ grab\\ meta.cf.organization\\ ))"
    space: "((\\ grab\\ meta.cf.space\\ ))"

- name: "deploy-master"
  type: "cf"
  source:
    api: "((\\ grab\\ meta.cf.api\\ ))"
    skip_cert_check: "((\\ grab\\ meta.cf.skip_cert_check\\ ))"
    username: "((\\ grab\\ meta.cf.username\\ ))"
    password: "((\\ grab\\ meta.cf.password\\ ))"
    organization: "((\\ grab\\ meta.cf.organization\\ ))"
    space: "((\\ grab\\ meta.cf.space\\ ))"
```

You can of course specify a `Path()` instance as second parameter to `.dump()` to write to file.